# Google Analytics: what does XX.XX% of total sessions means?

Tags: google-analytics, statistics

I opened Google Analytics website->Demographics->Overview and got following data of my android app:
[image]

There is a line at top right corner

```
71.12% of Total sessions
```

What does above line means to the data?

What about the remaining 28.88%?

Answer (score 2):

It's sampling. Google Analytics analyzes a sample set of data to extrapolate an estimate of 100% for certain non-default reports. This is common with most analytics tools as it saves huge amounts of space / CPU.

The thresholds for Google Analytics are thus:

*Default reports are not subject to sampling.*

*Ad-hoc queries of your data are subject to the following general thresholds for sampling:*

- *Analytics Standard: 500k sessions at the property level for the date range you are using*
- *Analytics 360: 100M sessions at the view level for the date range you are using*

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en

It is possible to get un-sampled data using the API but for most purposes, sampled data will still allow you to make actionable marketing decisions.

Answer (score 0):

It means Google was able to identify the age of the visitor during 71.12% of your site visits

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not correct. Do you have any references to verify that?

Comment: check this link support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en#where
Also you can test these %'s by creating respective demographics based segments such as these:
https://prnt.sc/i0u1qy
https://prnt.sc/i0u3e4
Apply these segments on the overview report and compare the %s.